# How to display a text histogram with proportions rather than raw numbers

Tags: c

From K&R C answer book exercise 1.13:

> Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of words in its input. It is easy to draw the histogram with the bars horizontal; a vertical orientation is more challenging.

I was able to make the horizontal histogram. The problem is my program prints an "X" for the amount of words per a given length, whereas in the book it does some kind of calculation to show the ratio of the amount of words per given length to the rest of the words.

First here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLENGTH 10
#define BORDERLENGTH 50

int main()
{
    int i, j, c, count;
    int ccount[MAXLENGTH];

    count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < MAXLENGTH; ++i)
        ccount[i] = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <=  'Z'))
            ++count;
        else if (count != 0){
            ++ccount[count - 1];
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < BORDERLENGTH; ++i)
        printf("-");
    printf("\n");
    count = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= MAXLENGTH; ++i){
        printf("%2d|", i);
        for (j = 0; j < ccount[count]; ++j )
            printf("x");
        ++count;
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < BORDERLENGTH; ++i)
        printf("-");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I've defined a word as any number or letter in sequence without any punctuation between or after them.

Notice, again, that my program outputs x number of "X"'s, where x is the number of words per a given word length. Would my method of output even be considered correct given what the exercise is asking for? I'm not really too familiar with what a histogram even is.

Now here is the program in the book:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXHIST 15
#define MAXWORD 11
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

main()
{
    int c, i, nc, state;
    int len;
    int maxvalue;
    int ovflow;
    int wl[MAXWORD];

    state = OUT;
    nc = 0;
    ovflow = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < MAXWORD; ++i)
        wl[i] = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'){
            state = OUT;
            if (nc > 0)
                if (nc < MAXWORD)
                    ++wl[nc];
                else 
                    ++ovflow;
            nc = 0;
        }
        else if (state == OUT){
            state = IN;
            nc = 1;
        } 
        else
            ++nc;
    }
    maxvalue = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < MAXWORD; ++i)
        if (wl[i] > maxvalue)
            maxvalue = wl[i];

    for (i = 1; i < MAXWORD; ++i){
        printf("%5d - %5d : ", i, wl[i]);
        if (wl[i] > 0){
            if ((len = wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue) <= 0)
                len = 1;
        }
        else
            len = 0;
        while (len > 0){
            putchar('*');
            --len;
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    if (ovflow > 0 )
        printf("There are %d words >= %d\n", ovflow, MAXWORD);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that this program defines what a word is different than what I do. It also contains overflowing checking. The part I'm confused with is this:

```
if (wl[i] > 0){
    if ((len = wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue) <= 0)
    len = 1;
}
else
    len = 0;
```

What is that `wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue` calculation in the `if` statement doing from a mathematical standpoint? How does it create a ratio between words. Is that a well-known formula?

Answer (score 2):

This calculation *normalizes* the values for showing them in a histogram. The program is set up in such a way as to always show the word with the highest counts as `MAXHIST` (i.e. 15) asterisks, regardless of how many words were counted. This is done to avoid histograms with very long rows of asterisks spawning multiple lines.

For example, if your file consists of 200 words, 150 of which are of length 4, and the remaining 50 are of length 2, the histogram will show 15 `*` characters for the four-letter words, and 5 `*` characters for two-letter words. If you give that program a file with 2000 words, 1500 of which have 4 letters and 500 have 2 letters, the histogram produced would be exactly the same.

Note that this scheme would produce incorrect results if applied in a straightforward way: for example, if your file contains 3000 four-letter words and only one two-letter word, normalizing 3000 to 15 characters would make the two-word line of asterisk less than a character wide. That is why there is an `if` condition that says that if a count is non-zero, at least one asterisk must be printed.

Answer (score 1):

The mathematical calculation is scaling down the value between `0` and `MAXHIST`, this is called *normalization*. It is useful as `maxvalue` is unpredictable and can be large. Normalization keeps them in a limit.

`wl[i] / maxvalue` scales down the value between `0` and `1`, and you can use whatever factor you want to scale it up, in this case `MAXHIST`.

Comment: Thanks. Is normalization something you learn in math and not in programming? I'm guessing it occurs a lot in programming because everyone mentioned it. I've only been through calculus 1.

Comment: @user3136710, normalization is not a programming thing. and it is not a topic in math too (surely, not anything like calculus or probability). Rather it is a general concept used very much in practical fields like digital signal processing etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's scaling the results to fit within the max amplitude of the histogram. `MAXHIST` is the maximum number of elements in the histogram, `maxvalue` is the length of the longest encountered. So `MAXHIST / maxvalue` gives you a scaling factor, when multiplied by the actual length of the current word you get how many elements to draw in that bar in the histogram.